# The function $\ \displaystyle f(x)=\int_{x}^{x^2}\!\!\!\! t \ln t\,dt$, $\ x>0 \ $ is increasing in what interval?

Tags: integration

The function $\ \displaystyle f(x)=\int_{x}^{x^2}\!\!\! t \ln t\,dt$, $\ x>0 \ $ is increasing in the interval

$$
(A)\left(\frac{1}{2},\infty\right)\qquad
(B)\left(0,\infty\right)\qquad
(C)\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)\qquad
(D) \text{ none }
$$

Its limits are not numbers,what to do? Kindly help?

Comment: Hint: Integrate by part

Comment: @tired Not necessarily (not even the best route, actually).

Comment: @Did i know that there are other possibilities, but because this question was classified as "integration" i thought the opener is maybe interested in an explicit calculation

Comment: @tired Your suggestion is more problematic than you think: once $f$ is known, one needs to determine its image--and for that I guess you will need $f'$... Hence the détour by $f$ is not needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$f'(x)=2x (2\ln(x)x^2)-x\ln(x)=x\ln(x)(4x^2-1)$

Thus, $f'(x)$ takes the sign of $\ln(x)(4x^2-1)$

Making a sign table for $\ln(x)$ and $(4x^2-1)$, you should be able to see that the solution is C.

Answer (score 0):

If $G(t)$ is a primitive of $tln(t)$ function then:
$$
f(x) = G(x^2) - G(x)
$$
and
$$
f'(x) = 2xG'(x^2) - G'(x)=2x * x^2 * ln(x^2) - x*lnx=4x^3lnx-xlnx=x(4x^2 - 1)lnx 
$$
For f to increase f' must be positive, so 
$$
x(4x^2 - 1)lnx > 0 
$$
therefore $0< x < 1/2$ or $x > 1$

Answer (score 0):

By integration by parts we get:f(x) = (x^2/4)((8lnx-1)(x^2-1)+4lnx). I drew the graph of this function and found that for x>0 the the function is increasing on the interval (0,1/2). After that, the function decreases until 0. Then after 0 it is increasing for ever. So the correct answer is C.